# How do I move a row with a recently edited cell to bottom?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So far, I have an excel sheet that displays information about parts and in column 'H' there is an initial column that when someone puts their initials in that column it indicates that the part is finished. The row with the new initials should go to the bottom of the data. However, before this happens I have already set up a userform, 'UserForm2' in which the user will put in a password. So, if I could get some guidance on how to go about doing that when they press the 'OkayButton', that would be amazing!

Edit: I have tried moving it down with the worksheet change event, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Edit2(defunct): I have sort of figured it out; However, the code that I've indicated below I have added is giving me a invalid qualifier error.

Edit3: Some progress! The newly changed code below does what I it to now; However the 'userform2' keeps popping up after it has been copied to the bottom, I'm not entirely sure why and if anyone would happen to know how to fix it and could tell me that would be much appreciated!

Edit4: It works!... For the most part. The error that was in the previous edit is still popping up. Again, the updated code is below.

Userform2:

```
    Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Unload Me
    End Sub
    Private Sub OkayButton_Click()
        IniPass = "pass"
        If Me.PasswordIn.Value = IniPass Then
            Unload Me
        Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
        If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "Please use the Cancel button to close the password window!"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Sheet1(LookUp):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    LooupValue = Target.Value
    part = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, MasterSheet.Range("A:AO"), 7, False)
    desc = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, MasterSheet.Range("A:AO"), 9, False)
    cust = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, MasterSheet.Range("A:AO"), 10, False)
    due = Application.VLookup(LooupValue, MasterSheet.Range("A:AO"), 13, False)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = part
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value = desc
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 5).Value = cust
        Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 6).Value = due
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        UserForm2.Show
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheet1.Rows(Target.Row).Cut Sheet1.Rows(lastRow).Offset(1, 0)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
            Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Userform2 is probably popping up because this `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then` is always evaluating to true. Does the range being passed into worksheet change always contain "H"?

Comment: Thank you for responding. TL;DR yes. An employee would enter their initials into that column, signifying that the part has been done, and after they put in the password, the row should be moved to the end of the table.

Comment: So then if "H:H" is always in the target range, intersect will never return `nothing` and your conditional will always be true which will lead to the `show` routine always being called. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Right, duh. I'm not sure how I would get around this, any suggestions?